# Speed up double nested sapply + lmer function in R

Tags: r

I am doing mixed modelling with lmer and would like to explore the effect of randomizing the data.  Can the following code be improved in terms of speed?  As is stands my current specs will require a few days to run my actual data...  From what I've been able to find, sapply is the way to go.  I'm hoping I'm wrong.

```
library(lme4)

##Generate real data
        real.data=data.frame(cat1=factor(rep(c("A","B","C","D"),500)),cat2=factor(rep(c("E","F","G","H"),500)), matrix(runif(12000),ncol=6))

##Apply lmer model for each data columm and extract variance estimates with VarCorr for 1000 randomizations of the real.data frame.

random=sapply(1:1000,function(z){print(z)

##Generate a randomized data set by sampling first two factor columns

    sample=data.frame(cat1=factor(sample(real.data$cat1)),cat2=factor(sample(real.data$cat2)), real.data[,3:8])

sapply(3:dim(sample)[2],function(y){print(y)

##Apply REML to each column of data, with 'cat1' and 'cat2' as random effects, including cat1:cat2 interaction

model=lmer(sample[,y]~(1|cat1)+(1|cat2)+(1|cat1:cat2), data=sample)

##Extract the estimates of the random effect terms
                c(as.numeric(VarCorr(model)$cat1),as.numeric(VarCorr(model)$cat2),as.numeric(VarCorr(model)$'cat1:cat2'))
})
})
```

Comment: Can you please explain in words what this means? Your function(z) scrambles the data, and then the function(y) scrambles it again. What are you trying to learn from this?

Comment: I apologize for not making it clear.  The function z randomizes the factor columns of the real.data frame.  Function y applies an REML model to the newly scrambled frame and then extracts the random effect estimates (in this case, "cat1" and "cat2"); this is done on a per column basis (one model per column of data).  Once models have been fitted to all the columns, the data is scrambled again, and it starts over.  The idea is to compare effect estimates from my real data to a distribution of effect estimates from 1000 randomized trials

Comment: I have edited the code to include a better explanation.  My first stackoverflow post :S.  I am open to suggestions for making it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sapply` and so forth won't save you much time, they're just
cleaner (sometimes).  On the other hand, once you have 
scrambled your factor columns you can use `refit` to re-fit
the model for different response data (i.e. columns) at some
savings in time.

I used the `plyr` package for a couple of things below.

It's not clear to me why you used `sample` to scramble
the order in which you fitted the different response
variables, so I left that part out ...

Preliminaries:

```
library(lme4)
library(plyr)
set.seed(101)
##Generate real data
real.data=data.frame(cat1=factor(rep(c("A","B","C","D"),500)),
cat2 <- factor(rep(c("E","F","G","H"),500)), matrix(runif(12000),ncol=6))
```

Here's the function to randomize the factor columns and fit the
model to a response based on each of columns 3 to 8 ...

```
sfun <- function() {
###Generate a randomized data set by sampling first two factor columns
    sampledat <- transform(real.data,
                           cat1=factor(sample(cat1)),
                           cat2=factor(sample(cat2)))
    ## fit first column
    m1 <- lmer(X1 ~ (1|cat1)+(1|cat2)+(1|cat1:cat2), data=sampledat)
    ## refit using every other column
    m_rest <- apply(real.data[,-(1:3)],2,
                     refit,object=m1)
    ## note this is 'laply' (from plyr), not 'lapply'
    laply(c(list(m1),m_rest),function(m) unlist(VarCorr(m)))
}
```

Now use `raply` to repeat.  The result is a 3D array with
dimensions (# sims)*(# response columns)*(# variance components).

```
nsim <- 50
sres <- raply(nsim,sfun(),.progress="text")
```

This took about 45 seconds on my laptop, so about 15 minutes to do 1000 reps ...

Comment: Very interesting.  Thank you!  I was unaware of the ability to "refit" the model.  Very useful.  As for the "sample scrambling", my real data set has 8 response variables, and perhaps stemming from my limited R experience I thought this an easy way to randomize (somewhat anyway).  I'm guessing you may be able to suggest a better method?

Comment: Scrambling the factors makes sense to me (although if your data are anywhere near normally distributed you will just be rederiving an F distribution), but I didn't understand why you were scrambling the order of your response variables, since you were re-fitting all of them anyway, and I don't see why the order would matter ...